# Execution time after adding indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing

Indexes increase data access performance. I tried creating indexes but there was no difference in the time cosumption. Am i missing something here?

My schema looks like this. (49 Columns). Id - PrimaryKey (Clustered Index)

```
Id | Name | Age | CountryId | CourseId | ....... | EnrolledOn
```

There are around 425,000 records in the table. Considering country and course are the columns used to filter the records, I created a composite index comprising these two columns (These two columns are foreign keys).

I tried the following query.

```
Select * From Students Where CountryId = 1 And CourseId = 1
```

Without indexes and with indexes the query took 11 seconds.

> Note : Around 415,000 records match the above condition. Will this be a reason for no difference in the time consumed.

Can anyone help me on this.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Country_Course ON Students(CountryId,CourseId)
```

Comment: The index may not be fully built yet - try rebuilding it - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187874(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: Look into using the SQL Server Query Analyzer.

Comment: Hi, yes, as almost the whole dataset matches into your condition, database engine will perform  full table scan. Try modifying the condition to a different, more unique country or course id and you should see the difference

Comment: Just adding indexes is not guaranteed to make queries faster. You need to be systematic about what indexes you add and ensure you are adding the right ones: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/10/back-index-basics-how-make-select-statements-faster-video/

Comment: @Oded: Sorry, But those are the two columns which would be used more frequently to search.

Comment: And why do you think an index will help SELECT * of almost the entire table? Indexes are not magic pixie dust. Maybe start by not using SELECT *, and/or choosing a where clause that eliminates more than 2-3% of the table.

Comment: The real question here is: are you wanting to pull back 400k records? Why? For what purpose? Pulling back 400k rows will take a good deal of time even if you don't have a where clause.

Comment: @SpectralGhost : I started to learn sql, When i came across indexes, i wanted to try by myself. May be i took wrong data.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand : So, this is where I was going wrong. Never knew that would be a problem. I am just a beginner to Sql. I never had a clue on this. Anyways thanks !

Comment: Thanks everyone. Might be a wrong question. But I am sure that I came to know many good things from your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index will do little if you request almost every row from a table. In that case it will only speedup if you only select fields that are in the index so the original table is not needed to get all requested data.

So select only countryid and you might see some benefit in the above problemcase

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `*` in your query, specify explicitly only the columns you want to select and also include those columns in your index as `included columns`..This would improve the selection time..

Hope you are aware that order of columns in index does matter..